# Android Landscape Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have an activity inside it I have a fragment (Rectangular Box). My landscape layout is not showing even if I had created. My portrait xml file is like this. 
 [First one land and second one is portrait and the down is the Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktIsv.png)
but when I turn my emulator to landscape mode it show as in Result in the image. 
but when change  `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` in manifest file, it comes perfect as I want but if I use `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize`.

It shows the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a folder inside `res/layout-land` and put the landscape view xml file inside this folder with the same name.This will Solve your problem.

[image]

Comment: I did that, I have create a layout-land folder. still

Comment: Both the Xml have the same name?

Comment: Yes!!
and I am using Glide for background image. It is not showing in emulator??

Comment: Is that fragment creating problem in landscape mode?

Comment: Try with activity?

Comment: I didn't understand the concept behind drawable-land??

Comment: I am using layout-land folder, In which I just want to change the fragment size and keep the buttons on right side of the fragment but it is not accessing the layout-land Xml file?